# CSS Styling Left and bottom border with angled tip

Tags: css, border

I'm trying to get some angle on the tip of a left and bottom border on a div or image. Can't seem to replicate this kind of style [Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCWPW.png)

This is what I have come up so far. When using borders angle tips are pointing outwards though

Using box shadow

```
<div class="container">Text Content or Image</div>

.container {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 100px;
  box-shadow: -10px 20px 0px 5px #f71e1e;
}
```

Using border

```
.container {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 100px;
  border-bottom: 15px solid #f71e1e;
  border-top: 15px solid white;
  border-left: 15px solid #f71e1e;
  border-right: 15px solid white;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/su8we1vq/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this would be by using multiple `box-shadow`, like this:

```
.container {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 100px;
  box-shadow: -1px 1px 0px #f71e1e,
    -2px 2px 0px #f71e1e,
    -3px 3px 0px #f71e1e,
    -4px 4px 0px #f71e1e,
    -5px 5px 0px #f71e1e,
    -6px 6px 0px #f71e1e,
    -7px 7px 0px #f71e1e,
    -9px 9px 0px #f71e1e,
    -10px 10px 0px #f71e1e;
}
```

Yeah, it doesn't look pretty syntax-wise but hey :(

Answer (score 3):

One approach is as follows, which does allow for easy changes to be made via CSS custom properties; the code is below with explanatory comments in the code:

```css
/* CSS custom properties to handle the border's
   color and size: */
:root {
  --borderColor: #f00;
  --borderSize: 10px;
}

/* simple reset to remove default margins and padding,
   and also forcing browsers to use the same basis for
   calculating element sizes: */
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  /* includes any assigned padding and border-widths
     in the declared size of the element: */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  background-color: blue;
  /* for no reason other than easily placing the contents of
     the element to the vertical center and left (inline-start): */
  display: grid;
  place-content: center start;
  block-size: 20vh;
  /* allows for responsive sizing, the preferred size is 80vw
     (80% of the viewport width), but with a minimum size of
     20rem and a maximum size of 1200px: */
  inline-size: clamp(20rem, 80vw, 1200px);
  /* in romantic languages, derivatives of Italian (English,
     German...) this is the top/bottom margin; we're using
     logical properties in order that other languages might be
     laid out appropriately for their own languages' inline and
     block axes): */
  margin-block: 20vh;
  /* in romantic languages (as above) this is equivalent to
     left/right margin: */
  margin-inline: auto;
  /* as above, but here we set padding on the inline-axis (left/right
     in romantic languages and derivatives): */
  padding-inline: 1em;
  /* to allow absolute positioning for pseudo-elements: */
  position: relative;
}

.container::before,
.container::after {
  content: '';
  background-color: var(--borderColor);
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: right top;
}

.container::before {
  /* taking the full size of the block axis of the parent: */
  block-size: 100%;
  /* sizing the inline axis to the desired size of the "border" */
  inline-size: var(--borderSize);
  top: 0;
  right: 100%;
  /* skewing the normal quadrilateral shape of an HTML element: */
  transform: skewY(-45deg);
}

.container::after {
  /* the size of the desired "border": */
  block-size: var(--borderSize);
  /* the full inline size of the parent: */
  inline-size: 100%;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  transform: skewX(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<!-- the original HTML: -->
<div class="container">Text Content or Image</div>
<!-- a second element, demonstrating the possible "theming": -->
<div class="container"
     style="--borderColor: lightskyblue;
            --borderSize: 2em;
            background-color: palegreen;">Text Content or Image</div>
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hxzqrewj/).

It's worth noting though that there is a slight problem with this approach, where the two pseudo-elements meet, on the lower-left, there is a visible sliver of the `background-color` of whatever is behind the element.

Answer (score 2):

clip-path with border can do it. I added a CSS variable to easily control the size of the shadow

```css
.box {
  --s: 10px; /* control the size of the shadow */
  
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid #f71e1e; /* the color here */
  border-width: 0 0 var(--s) var(--s);
  clip-path: polygon(0 var(--s),var(--s) 0, 100% 0,100% 100%,100% calc(100% - var(--s)),calc(100% - var(--s)) 100%,0 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Also with multiple background to have less code:

```css
.box {
  --s: 10px; /* control the size of the shadow */
  
  margin: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  background: 
   linear-gradient(blue 0 0) calc(100% + var(--s)) calc(-1*var(--s)) no-repeat,
   #f71e1e;
  clip-path: polygon(0 var(--s),var(--s) 0, 100% 0,100% 100%,100% calc(100% - var(--s)),calc(100% - var(--s)) 100%,0 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```